# About ALSA sound

Tags: alsa

The `aplay` command can determine the correct card and slot to play the sound.

Can I use `aplay` before configuring `/etc/asound.conf` or `.asoundrc`?  Or is it necessary to write this configuration before using `aplay`.

Answer (score 2):

There is a global configuration file, typically `/usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf`, with default settings. In most cases, the default settings will work.